# How to install keryx?

Tags: python, repository, downgrade

How to install keryx in ubuntu 12.04? knowing that keryx1.0 needs python <2.7 and ubuntu 12.04 has python2.7.3 so what could i do either to downgrade python or installing keryx bas some way.

Also any suggestions replacing keryx for offline repositories are also very welcomed

Comment: Here is the bug on this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/keryx/+bug/820664 You might consider signing up for it and add yourself as affected by it. It also says in comments: install from source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [keryx portable](https://launchpad.net/keryx/stable/1.0-release/+download/keryx_1.0-public21_portable.zip)  It works in ubuntu 12.04

1. Download [keryx portable](https://launchpad.net/keryx/stable/1.0-release/+download/keryx_1.0-public21_portable.zip)
2. Extract the Downloaded file
3. goto ../Downloads/keryx_1.0-public21_portable/bin
4. Double click on keryx.py and choose run/run in terminal